# iOS Dev - Hook to app audio output

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, record

is there a way to receive the audio output of an app vie another app (my app)?

say for example, an app that record the audio of the YouTube app and save it into a file.

oh and, of course, not using the mic....

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, but only on iOS 7 with [Inter-app Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW32). Not sure if can do this with the YouTube app since it will not run in background also all the other app will need to support inter-app audio.

Comment: thanks for the comment! for apps that does not support inter-app audio this is not possible? are there any low-level stuff that can be done?

Comment: @user3157407 there is nothing that could be done unless you plan to reverse and hack the original app.